# erro em update mysql

Tags: mysql, asp, sql-update

Estou a receber este erro quando tento fazer o update com mysql em asp.

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/postos/reg.asp, line 525

set ins_regenf1 = conn.Execute("UPDATE reg SET hemo ='"&hemo &"' WHERE id_reg='"&id_ficha&"';")
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

Eu sei que parece obvio mas os valores estao correctos assim como as defenicoes na bd esta correcta.

Alguem tem alguma ideia do que se esta a passar?
Obrigado

Comment: Ricardo, aqui só devem ser postadas perguntas em português.

Comment: Não reperei que estava no pt, vou mudar. obrigado

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `hemo`?

Comment: texto, e esta na bd como varchar

Comment: `Conteúdo`. Qual o texto?

Comment: tente tirar o ";" de dentro do parenteses !

Comment: Ja tirei e faz o mesmo :/

Comment: é de teste.. tipo "fdjklshfldhs"

Comment: Tu consegue rodar um update exatamente igual a esse direto no `mysql`?

Comment: da-me este erro "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."  mas nao tem logica o unico campo key é id que é de numeração automatica

Comment: verifique o tipo de campo no mysql e se for varchar(5) veja a quantidade de caracteres permitidos se está dentro do que foi configurado, verifique se os nomes dos campos estão corretos na query de acordo com o criado no banco de dados.